# WebSocket PHP + JS

Tags: websocket

I'm trying to set up WebSocket for my web application. I have found some doc and example with google but i don't understand very well what i am supposed to do to send additionnal data when the socket open. 
I would like to have a User array which contain user socket and user id but i can't send userID in JavaScript at the opening of the socket and get that UserId in PHP on my server.
My application have to send a message to a specific client identified by UserID (UserID is stored in DB but i supposed that my client code in JS normally can send that).
For the moment I a socket list but i want to replace it by a User list which contain id and socket.

PHP SERVER CODE

```
$host = 'localhost'; //host
$port = '9000'; //port
$null = NULL; //null var
//Create TCP/IP sream socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
//reuseable port
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

//bind socket to specified host
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);

//listen to port
socket_listen($socket);

//create & add listning socket to the list
$sockets = array($socket);
$users = array();
//$clients = array($socket);

//start endless loop, so that our script doesn't stop
while (true) {
    //manage multipal connections
    $changed = $sockets;
    //returns the socket resources in $changed array
    socket_select($changed, $null, $null, 0, 10);

    //check for new socket
    if (in_array($socket, $changed)) {
        $socket_new = socket_accept($socket); //accept new socket
        // HERE I NEED USER ID BUT I DON'T FIND HOW TO GET IT
        $clients[] = $socket_new; //add socket to client array

        $header = socket_read($socket_new, 1024); //read data sent by the socket
        perform_handshaking($header, $socket_new, $host, $port); //perform websocket handshake

        socket_getpeername($socket_new, $ip); //get ip address of connected socket
        $response = mask(json_encode(array('type' => 'system', 'message' => $ip . ' connected'))); //prepare json data
        send_message($response); //notify all users about new connection
        //make room for new socket
        $found_socket = array_search($socket, $changed);
        unset($changed[$found_socket]);
    }

    //loop through all connected sockets
    foreach ($changed as $changed_socket) {

        //check for any incomming data
        while (socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1) {
            $received_text = unmask($buf); //unmask data
            $tst_msg = json_decode($received_text); //json decode 
            $user_id = $tst_msg->iduser;
            $user_name = $tst_msg->name; //sender name
            $user_message = $tst_msg->message; //message text
            $user_color = $tst_msg->color; //color
            //prepare data to be sent to client
            $response_text = mask(json_encode(array('type' => 'usermsg', 'name' => $user_name, 'message' => $user_message, 'color' => $user_color)));
            send_message($response_text); //send data
            break 2; //exist this loop
        }

        $buf = @socket_read($changed_socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
        if ($buf === false) { // check disconnected client
            // remove client for $clients array
            $found_socket = array_search($changed_socket, $clients);
            socket_getpeername($changed_socket, $ip);
            unset($clients[$found_socket]);

            //notify all users about disconnected connection
            $response = mask(json_encode(array('type' => 'system', 'message' => $ip . ' disconnected')));
            send_message($response);
        }
    }
}
// close the listening socket
socket_close($sock);

function send_message($msg) {
    global $clients;
    foreach ($clients as $changed_socket) {
        @socket_write($changed_socket, $msg, strlen($msg));
    }
    return true;
}

//Unmask incoming framed message
function unmask($text) {
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if ($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    } elseif ($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    } else {
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i % 4];
    }
    return $text;
}

//Encode message for transfer to client.
function mask($text) {
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if ($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif ($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif ($length >= 65536)
        $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
    return $header . $text;
}

//handshake new client.
function perform_handshaking($receved_header, $client_conn, $host, $port) {
    $headers = array();
    $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $receved_header);
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $line = chop($line);
        if (preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches)) {
            $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
    }

    $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
    $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
    //hand shaking header
    $upgrade = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
            "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
            "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
            "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
            "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/demo/shout.php\r\n" .
            "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
    socket_write($client_conn, $upgrade, strlen($upgrade));
}

function getSocketbyIdUser($idU) {
    global $clients;
    foreach ($clients as $client) {
        if ($client->getIdUser() == $idU) {
            return $client->getSocket();
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function userIsConnected($idU) {
    global $clients;
    return getSocketbyIdUser($idU) != false;
}

function getSocketsArray() {
    global $clients;
    $sockets[];
    foreach ($clients as $client) {

        $sockets[] = $client->getSocket();
    }
    return $sockets;
}

class Client {

    private $idUser;
    private $socket;

    public function getIdUser() {
        return self::$idUser;
    }

    public function getSocket() {
        return self::$socket;
    }

}
```

JS CODE

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //create a new WebSocket object.
        var wsUri = "ws://localhost:9000/server/server.php";    
        websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); 

        websocket.onopen = function(ev) { // connection is open 
                $('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">Connected!</div>"); //notify user
        }

        $('#send-btn').click(function(){ //use clicks message send button   
                var mymessage = $('#message').val(); //get message text
                var myname = $('#name').val(); //get user name

                if(myname == ""){ //empty name?
                        alert("Enter your Name please!");
                        return;
                }
                if(mymessage == ""){ //emtpy message?
                        alert("Enter Some message Please!");
                        return;
                }

                //prepare json data
                var msg = {
                message: mymessage,
                name: myname,
                color : '<?php echo $colours[$user_colour]; ?>'
                };
                //convert and send data to server
                websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
        });

        //#### Message received from server?
        websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {
                var msg = JSON.parse(ev.data); //PHP sends Json data
                var type = msg.type; //message type
                var umsg = msg.message; //message text
                var uname = msg.name; //user name
                var ucolor = msg.color; //color

                if(type == 'usermsg') 
                {
                        $('#message_box').append("<div><span class=\"user_name\" style=\"color:#"+ucolor+"\">"+uname+"</span> : <span class=\"user_message\">"+umsg+"</span></div>");
                }
                if(type == 'system')
                {
                        $('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">"+umsg+"</div>");
                }

                $('#message').val(''); //reset text
        };

        websocket.onerror   = function(ev){$('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_error\">Error Occurred - "+ev.data+"</div>");}; 
        websocket.onclose   = function(ev){$('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">Connection Closed</div>");}; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Send your additional data to `websocket` like this: 
`ws://yoursite:port/?param1=value;`
In server:

```
if (preg_match("/GET (.*) HTTP/", $receved_header, $match)) {
$root = $match[1];
$userid = explode('param1=', $root);
if (!empty($userid) && array_key_exists(1, $param1))
$this->userid = $userid[1];
}
```

it works for me..try it